# $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t) dt =\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have studied *Advanced Calculus* by Fitzpatrick which discusses the so called the Second Fundamental Theorem (Differentiating Integrals) but it is when the upper or lower limits of integral is a function of $x$ and differentiation is on $x$. But differentiation of the type in the title is not discussed at all and is used in another textbook without a proof; so what is a clear proof for equation $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t) \ dt =\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t) \ dt?$$

Comment: Write a difference quotient of two integrals, write the two integrals as limits of Riemann sums, and then interchange the order of the $n \to \infty$ limit in the Riemann sums and the $h \to 0$ limits in the derivatives. The difficulty is showing when/why you can do this interchange.

Comment: @Ian, the function is considered to be $f(x,t) = t^{x-1} e^{-t}$. So I think I can interchange the limit and integral as $f(x,t)$ is uniformly continuous? And, what "difference quotient of two integrals" means?

Comment: I mean that the left side is by definition $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_a^b f(x+h,t) dt - \int_a^b f(x,t) dt}{h}$. Using linearity you can simplify this to $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_a^b f(x+h,t)-f(x,t) dt}{h}$. Now you write this inner integral as a limit of Riemann sums, and then interchange the two limits. This requires some regularity out of $f$, though.

Comment: @Ian, could you provide more detailed proof as you see how the conversation went on with the other answer! You know exactly what I mean but I can't prove it myself. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a decently behaving $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)$ one has $f(x,t)=f(x_0,t)+\int_{x_0}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,t)\ dy\ $ and therefore $$\int_a^b f(x,t) \ dt=\int_a^b f(x_0,t) \ dt+\int_a^b\int_{x_0}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,t)\ dy\ dt=$$ $$=\int_a^b f(x_0,t) \ dt + \int_{x_0}^x\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,t)\ dt\ dy$$
and $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t) \ dt=\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{x_0}^x\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,t)\ dt\ dy=\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(y,t) \ dt$$

Comment: Good.  Note random's interchange theorem was Fubini, which has some hypotheses to verify.  But certainly they are OK if $f \in C^1$ so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)$ is a continuous function of the two variables.

Answer (score 2):

A proof would use some "limit theorem" to interchange integral and limit.  Probably in a course with only Riemann integration we would use uniform convergence for that.  But in a course with Lebesgue integration we could use a monotone convergence or dominated convergence argument.  Here we mark with $\overset{*}{=}$ where the limit theorem must be used.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t)\;dt &=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_a^b f(x+h,t)\;dt -  \int_a^b f(x,t)\;dt\right) 
\\ &=
\lim_{h\to 0}\int_a^b\frac{1}{h}\big(  f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)\big)\;dt
\\ &\overset{*}{=}
\int_a^b\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\big(  f(x+h,t) - f(x,t)\big)\;dt
\\ &=
\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)\;dt
\end{align}

The remainder of the argument would use assumed properties of $f(x,t)$ in order to verify the hypotheses of the limit theorem you wish to use at $\overset{*}{=}$.

Comment: Thank you, this is great answer! - 1. Shouldn't it be properties of $\frac1h (f(x+h,t) -f(x,t))$ rather than $f(x,t)$? Which makes it difficult even if we know about $f$ itself? 2. A typo in the beginning: $d/dx$ for $d/dt$.

Comment: @Edi  2. typo fixed ... 1. Presumably the hypothesis is about $f(x,t)$, and then in order to prove it we have to deduce properties of $\frac1h (f(x+h,t) -f(x,t))$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall [Leibniz's integral rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html)

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} f(t,s) ds = \int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s) ds+f(t,\psi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) -f(t,\phi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)$$

Notice that if ${\displaystyle \psi(t)}$and ${\displaystyle \phi(t)} $are constants rather than functions of ${\displaystyle t} $, we have a special case of Leibniz's rule:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{b} f(t,s) ds = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s) ds+f(t,b)\cdot 0 -f(t,a)\cdot0$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{b} f(t,s) ds = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s) ds$$

The formula you are looking for is nothing but a special case of Leibniz's rule.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. This is a generalized version of my question which is asked several times on MSE and the equation in my question is considered to be known to the reader in all of them. But I don't know the special case at the first place!

Comment: It is even given on the wiki have a look if you want to I think my answer is correct I don't know what are you looking for

Comment: I am working on @Ian 's hint but it's difficult although if I can get it right that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Your answer is correct if I know how you entered $d/dt$ from outside to the inside of integral. That's all I need to prove. [PS I unfortunately am in Turkey now and wiki is blocked in this *Republic*...]

Comment: I didn't enter d/dt inside the integral  look at the first equation  it is already there in the first term I just replace $\psi(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ with constants  b,a thus there differentiation becomes 0 and you get your answer

Comment: I meant to ask entering  d/dt inside the integral at the *first* equation, actually. Could you let me know where can I find a clear proof for the first equation in your answer (I don't want take your time much if it is lengthy and if there a link already, thanks)

Comment: I don't about the proof but it is Leibnitz General integration rule https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

Comment: Yes it's exactly the first equation in the link you provided that I am trying to prove. I am searching still.. :) Thanks.

Comment: dude your question is different in the title  you said you want to prove 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t) dt =\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$

Now you are saying you want to prove 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} f(t,s) ds = \int_{\phi(t)}^{\psi(t)} \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s) ds+f(t,\psi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) -f(t,\phi(t))\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t)$$

Ask a different question for the proof of Leibnitz General differentiation rule. I don't know if the proof even exits

Comment: The first equation (5th line) in the link https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/ is $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,t) dt =\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$ and that's the only one I want to prove.

Comment: I have already provided a proof for that in my answer please just once read it calmly and carefully you will understand it. It is nothing but the special case of general Rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82443/discussion-between-james-and-edi).

Comment: Why the downvote though I have answered my best and it is correct according to me hey @Edi was it you? or someone else

Answer (score 0):

"Fundamental Theorem (Differentiating Integrals) but it is when the upper or lower limits of integral is a function of x and differentiation is on x"

might not count as a proof but just an observation I thought might be useful,

when you mentioned that the limits of the integral are a function of x, your limits in this case be taken as :
f1(x)=a and f2(x)=b
in which case the proof given in the book would suffice..